# Can anyone help me identify this Japanese(HNK) font..?

Tags: fonts

It's used on NHK( Japan Broadcasting Corparation ) logo.
[image]

I have searched all over Google and everything.. It can't be found, witch is why I am asking here.. Thanks in advance..!! :):)

Comment: Being a logo for a large company it's probably not a font. My guess is that the letters are constructed specifically for this logo. Very simple shapes really. Can you find any example of other words written with this font?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Searching on google is no good. You should use a service such as [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to find a similar font. There are several fonts that are similar.

Comment: I suspect @Wolff is correct. You can find an SVG (vector) of the logo here:  https://logos.fandom.com/wiki/NHK#2020.E2.80.93present (whether it's "official" or not, I don't know). It contains no fonts/fonted text, just simple shapes.

Answer (score -4):

Usually logo's for companies, small or big doesn't matter, are SVG's. This helps scaling and keeping the logo sharp on every type of design.